# How to boot live debian using persistence image in read-only mode?

Tags: debian, filesystems, persistence

I created live usb using a live image of [debian stretch](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/release/9.0.1-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-9.0.1-amd64-mate.iso) on `kernel 4.9.0-3-adm64`, and then installed persistence image file on root of data partition which contains `/boot/grub` and `/live/filesystem.squashfs`.

Now grub is able to boot debian in persistence mode by following kernel commands:

```
linux /live/vmlinux-4.9.0-3-amd64 boot=live components persistence
initrd /live/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Persistence storage setup works as expected, but I'm looking to boot the filesystem in read-only mode while using persistence storage, `live-boot` man page ([here](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/live-boot-doc/live-boot.7.en.html)) introduces `persistence-read-only`:

> **persistence-read-only**
>
> Filesystem changes are not saved back to
>   persistence media. In  particular, overlays and netboot NFS mounts are
>   mounted read-only.

and Debian [`Live Systems Manual`](https://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/live-manual/stable/manual/html/live-manual.en.html) doesn't say too much about this.

I tied following kernel options, none of them work:

```
# it not even load persistence image! also tried with "persistence-label=persistence"
linux /live/vmlinux-4.9.0-3-amd64 boot=live components persistence persistence-read-only
initrd /live/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64

# loads persistence image, but it's not ro 
linux /live/vmlinux-4.9.0-3-amd64 boot=live components ro persistence
initrd /live/initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

When searching boot logs for `peristence` and `persistent` keywords, I cannot find anything more than the above `kernel command line`s.

I also read [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=129732) brilliant post at Debian forums, but even his/her command line doesn't work for me.

**Question in short:**

How can I boot Debian live image 4.9.0-3, loading persistence image, but not writing back changes to it?!

Comment: Why would you configure persistence and then try to force not to write back filesystem changes? I don't understand your goal. Do you realize that you can use the live Debian and make changes to the root file system without persistence per definition of "live"?

Comment: Here my goal is to not write back changes by default, maintaining always a fresh boot while saving occasionally changes manually or from certain boots. I use persistence definition and not a filesystem partition because filesystem.squashfs compresses my large filesystem very well. From debian `live-boot` I realize that there is option for this goal, but unfortunately the option seems to not work in my setup.